# Is it possible to use Jfree chart with matrix?

Tags: java, jfreechart

First I want to say sorry I am not a programmer, I just need to solve this calculation.
I have two (for loops), each time when the loop is working, should draw a new line.
So is there any way to do something like XYSeriesCollection Z[Matrix]? because my drawing is wrong. Please help me to find a soulution.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory; 
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
//Please The Question is just about the Chart, I know the code is 
//horrible.
public class Loop extends ApplicationFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static int A=1, B=A+1, j;
public static double F; 
public static double F_Starting_Value=(double)Math.round(0.009   *1000d)/1000d;
public static double F_End_Value=((double)Math.round(1.0   *10d)/10d);
public static double F_Step=((double)Math.round(0.001      *1000d)/1000d);
public static int MatrixSize=1000;
public static double [] z1 = new double [MatrixSize];
public static double [] z2 = new double [MatrixSize];
public static double [] ZResult = new double [MatrixSize];
    //Factorial 
    public static int Factorial(int n) 
    {
        int temp=1, fact=1;
        for(int i=n; i>0;i--) {
        temp=i*fact;;
        fact=temp;
        }
        return fact;
    }
    // Psi
    public static double []Psi()
    {
        double []temp = new double [MatrixSize]; 
        double [] p = new double [MatrixSize];
        for ( F=((double)Math.round(F_Starting_Value*1000d)/1000d),j=0;
        F < ((double)Math.round(F_End_Value*1000d)/1000d) && j<MatrixSize;
        F+=((double)Math.round(F_Step*1000d)/1000d), j++)
        {
            for (int i= A; i<= B; i++) 
            {
            temp[j]=0;
                temp [j]= Math.pow(((double)Math.round(F*1000d)/1000d), i)
                    *Math.pow(1-((double)Math.round(F*1000d)/1000d),B-i)
                    *((Factorial(B))/(Factorial(B-i)*Factorial(i)));

                    p[j] += ((double)Math.round(temp [j]*1000000000d)/1000000000d);
            }
        }
        return p;
    }
    public Loop( String applicationTitle, String chartTitle ) {
        super(applicationTitle);
        JFreeChart xylineChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                chartTitle ,
                "D" ,
                "Benefit Z " ,
                createDataset() ,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL ,
                true , true , false);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel( xylineChart );
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize( new java.awt.Dimension( 600, 500 ) );
        final XYPlot plot = xylineChart.getXYPlot( );
        //Line colors and width  
          XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer( );
          renderer.setSeriesPaint( 0 , Color.YELLOW );
          renderer.setSeriesPaint( 1 , Color.GREEN );
          renderer.setSeriesPaint( 2 , Color.RED );
          renderer.setSeriesStroke( 0 , new BasicStroke( 3.0f ) );
          renderer.setSeriesStroke( 1 , new BasicStroke( 4.0f ) );
          renderer.setSeriesStroke( 2 , new BasicStroke( 5.0f ) );
          plot.setRenderer( renderer ); 
          setContentPane( chartPanel ); 
       }
    //Data input
    private XYDataset createDataset( ) {
        final XYSeries Z = new XYSeries( "Relation between D" );
        // All about THIS PART       
        double [] psi=Psi();
        int D;
        for(D=2;D<10;D++) {  
            for ( F=0.001, j=0;F<1.0 && j<1000;
            F+=((double)Math.round(0.001*1000d)/1000d), j++)
            {
            z1[j]=((double)Math.round(F*1000d)/1000d)/((D-1)*
                    (1-((double)Math.round(F*1000d)/1000d))+1);
            z2[j]=(A*psi[j])/( (1-psi[j])*(D-1)+ B);
            ZResult[j]=z2[j]-z1[j];
            if (ZResult[j] > 0)
                {
                Z.add(D, ((double)Math.round(ZResult[j] *100000000d)/100000000d));
                }
            }
        }
              //Data output 
        final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection( );          
        dataset.addSeries( Z );
        return dataset;
    }
       public static void main( String[ ] args )
       {
           Loop chart = new Loop("",
                  "Max Z");
          chart.pack( );          
          RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen( chart );          
          chart.setVisible( true );
       }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please take a tour and see how to ask a good question: [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). It is really unclear where you want to implement your changes and why you are failing in doing so ...

Answer (score 1):

A very basic principle in programming is: DRY (Don't repeat yourself). Although I have absolutely no clue what your calculation is doing in particular, it's pretty obvious you're calculating the same things over and over again. Instead of copying your code and just changing the argument of the for-loop (and one argument in the `Math.pow`-function call), you could just write an extra function for that:

```java
public static double []psi(int aParameter, int bParameter) {
    double []temp = new double [MatrixSize]; 
    double [] p = new double [MatrixSize];
    //==========Изменение точности=============
     for ( F=((double)Math.round(F_Starting_Value*1000d)/1000d),j=0;
             F < ((double)Math.round(F_End_Value*1000d)/1000d) && j<MatrixSize;
             F+=((double)Math.round(F_Step*1000d)/1000d), j++)
    {
        for (int i= aParameter; i<= bParameter; i++) 
        {
        temp[j]=0;
            temp [j]= Math.pow(((double)Math.round(F*1000d)/1000d), i)
                *Math.pow(1-((double)Math.round(F*1000d)/1000d),bParameter-i)
                *((Facterial(bParameter))/(Facterial(bParameter-i)*Facterial(i)));
                p[j] += ((double)Math.round(temp [j]*1000000000d)/1000000000d);
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Of course, you should choose more descriptive parameter names than `aParameter` and `bParameter`, based on what they're representing.

You can apply the same principle to almost all other parts of your code. However, since it's not my job to solve your problem entirely, I'll leave the rest to you. If you have any further questions, just ask.

Comment: Thank you for replaying! I know my code is not good enough and there are a lot to correct. but the code is not important. just the result. I just want to get these charts with different D. I eddited my question. just the chart part is important.